# Why can't I directly access (and lock) the implicit lock that Objects use for synchronized block

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, blocking, synchronized

*rephrased for clarity*

I would like to be able to mix the use of the synchronized block with more explicit locking via calling lock and release methods directly when appropriate.  Thus allowing me the syntaxtical sugar of using sychtronized(myObject) when I can get away with it, but also being able to call myObject.lock & myObject.unlock dierctly for those times when a synchronized block is not flexible enough to do what I need done.

I know that every single Object has, implicitly, a rentrant lock built into it which is used by the synchronized block.  Effectively the the lock mthod is caled on the Objects internal reentrant lock every time one enters a sychronized block, and unlock is called on the same reentrant lock when you leave the synchronized block.  I would seem as if it wouldn be easy enough to allow one the ability to manually lock/unlock this inplicit reentrant lock; thus allowing a mixing of synchronized blocks and explcit locking.

However, as far as I know there is no way to do this.  And because of the way synchronized blocks work I don't believe there is a convenient way to mix them with explicit locking othewrise.  It seems as if this would be a rather convenient, and easily added by expending the Object api to add lock/unlock methods.

The question I have is, why doesn't this exist?  I'm certain there is a reason, but I don't know what it is.  I thought the issue may be with encapsulation; same reason you don't want to do synchronize(this).  However, if I am already calling sycnhronized(myObject) then by defination anyone who knows about myObject can likewise synchronize on it and cause a deadlock if done foolishly.  The question of encapsulation comes down to who can access the object you synchronized on regardless of rather you use a sychtronized block or manually locked the object; at least as I see it.  So is there some other advantage to not allowing one to manually lock an object?

Comment: Just to be clear (and to prevent answers like my now-deleted one, and the one that followed it), you're saying you want to synchronize on the same monitor, but you **don't** want to use the `synchronize` statement. You want (effectively) to get some kind of monitor object and call a `lock` method on it, do other logic, and call a `release` on it. So it's not a question about synchronized methods vs. synchronized blocks, but about using the same monitor via explicit "lock" and "release" "calls."

Comment: Now I am not sure what he wants to know, The last paragraph make sense as an advanced OO design topic, the first paragraph are question from a beginner in thread safety; in the middle paragraph he taks about sycronized blocks, wher he may  meant syncronied methods, or syncronizing on this. All a bit confusing

Comment: yes TJ, I am asking what you said.  I'm sorry if I didn't phrase it well, I couldn't think of how to present what I wanted clearly

Comment: The question is very good, +1, but I'm afraid it will be soon closed as "Not a real question", because there is not a single answer for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locks of a certain object is highly tied to the instance itself. The structure of the `synchronized` blocks and methods are very strict. If you, as a programmer, would have the possibility to interfere with the system (virtual machine), it could cause serious problems.

- You could eventually release a lock that was created by a `synchronized` block
- You create a lock that another `synchronized` block will release
- You create more lock entries than exits
- You create more lock exits than entries

There are even specific bytecodes defined for the `lock` and `release` operations. If you would have a "method" for this lock/unlock operation, it should be compiled to these bytecodes. So, it is *really* a low-level operation, and very much different from other Java object level implementations.

Synchronisation is a very strong contract. I think that the designers of the JLS did not want to allow the possibility to break this contract.

The [Chapter 17 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) describes more about the expected behaviour.