# Can I access the Lock used by a synchronized block in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

Having a simple List:

```
private final List<Item> lst = new ArrayList();
```

When I need synchronization, I used to do the following:

```
synchronized (lst) {
    // Some code
}
```

Now, I need to create a `Condition` object using `Lock.newCondition()`, can I access the underlying lock used by `synchronized{}` to use it to create my condition, or should I remove synchronized blocks and use a custom `Lock` object ?

Comment: The latter. The two are difference constructs.

Comment: You may want to give more context - a Condition may not be necessary for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927011/why-cant-i-directly-access-and-lock-the-implicit-lock-that-objects-use-for-sy?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a Condition object, is a clear sign that intrinsic locking are not enough for you. You will need to use

```
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
```

Anyway, if you are worried about performances, that is not a problem with modern virtual machines. Explicit locking perform as well as intrinsic one.

Comment: and if you are doing that, you probably can remove the intrinsic locking. No need for both usually.

Comment: I'd say, you almost likely HAVE to remove it, as acquiring two locks without a precise acquisition order can lead to deadlock. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)